# While trying to make a walk/run animation CTRL+SHIFT+V doesn't work correctly

Tags: animation, mesh, armature, bones, edit-mode

So, I'm following a tutorial to create a character + his walk and run animations.
The tutorial says to create half an animation and then we copy and mirror the 2nd half.
In the video - everything mirrors correctly for the guy, but for me mirrors the upper half of the body correctly (same position, angles etc. of the arms), but legs get deformed a bit.

As seen in these pictures (frame 1 and frame 9 which needs to be opposite to frame 1)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Are the bones perfectly mirrored? Try to see if the roll is the same on both the right and left leg in edit mode. Otherwise it could be an inverse kinematic issue.

Comment: Meant to say the legs should have OPPOSITE rolls (one positive one negative, same number).

Comment: @moonboots [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=Jd99ajsV" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/Jd99ajsV/) here you go, didn't know how to do it when I created the problem. Thank you

Comment: @MrWaffleman I've done my model using the mirror modifier and after adding the core bones (middle) and the left side - I've used the 'Symetrize' option and when I reset the mesh with ALT+R & ALT+G to remove all rotations and such, it's symetrical! The left lower leg is at -177° and the right one has 177° roll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symmetry of the IK controllers is bad, here is what we have currently:

[image]

If I delete the right leg and symmetrize the left leg, here is what I have:

[image]

Now it works correctly, except I'm not sure about your feet *Copy Rotation* constraint but it's another problem... (I would rather parent the feet to the controllers and give them a *Copy Location* with the lower legs as targets and the *Head/Tail* value at 1).

Comment: SOLVED! Firstly, I wanna thank you. Really don't know how the symmetry got messed up since I selected everything and did the symmetrize, but does not matter now. I'm quite new to blender and for now I'm just following some basic tutorials and that's what the guy did in the video. After I get everything up and running, I'll re-do it and try your solution for the feet. Once again, thank you very much!